# Can GCM auth be bitsliced?

Tags: gcm, bitslicing

Is it possible to use bitslicing for GCM?  This seems like a way to allow for a way to avoid cache-timing attacks without PCLMUL instructions and with good performance.

Comment: You can check [Faster and Timing-Attack Resistant AES-GCM](http://www.iacr.org/archive/ches2009/57470001/57470001.pdf) by Emilia et al.